# NullPointer al abrir una ventana desde otra

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo dos ventanas que os muestro a continuación:

`vistaAlbumesBuscar`

```
public class VistaAlbumesBuscar extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

/**
 * Componentes de la ventana
 */
private Coordinador miCoordinador;
private JTextField campoTextoArtista, campoTextoAlbum;
private JLabel etiquetaArtista, etiquetaAlbum, etiquetaArtista2, etiquetaAlbum2, etiquetaCanciones;
private JSeparator separador;
private JButton botonModificar, botonEliminar, botonEliminar2, botonAdd;
private JList listaCanciones;
private DefaultListModel modeloLista;
private JScrollPane scrollListadoCanciones;
private JComboBox elegirAlbum, elegirArtista;
private DefaultComboBoxModel modeloCombo;
private Generador miGenerador;

/**
 * Iniciamos la ventana
 */
public VistaAlbumesBuscar() {
    iniciarVentana();
}

/**
 * Contenido de la ventana.
 */
private void iniciarVentana() {

    /*Propiedades Frame*/
    setTitle("Albums: Search");
    setBounds(100, 100, 353, 437);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    /*Etiqueta Artista*/
    etiquetaArtista = new JLabel("Artist:");
    etiquetaArtista.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaArtista.setBounds(10, 11, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaArtista);

    /*Etiqueta de Album*/
    etiquetaAlbum = new JLabel("Album:");
    etiquetaAlbum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaAlbum.setBounds(10, 36, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaAlbum);

    /*Separador*/
    separador = new JSeparator();
    separador.setBounds(0, 76, 337, 2);
    getContentPane().add(separador);

    /*Etiqueta Artista II*/
    etiquetaArtista2 = new JLabel("Artist:");
    etiquetaArtista2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaArtista2.setBounds(10, 89, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaArtista2);

    /*Campo texto Artista*/
    campoTextoArtista = new JTextField();
    campoTextoArtista.setBounds(62, 89, 231, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoArtista);
    campoTextoArtista.setColumns(10);
    campoTextoArtista.setEditable(false);

    /*Etiqueta Album II*/
    etiquetaAlbum2 = new JLabel("Album:");
    etiquetaAlbum2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaAlbum2.setBounds(10, 121, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaAlbum2);

    /*Campo texto Album*/
    campoTextoAlbum = new JTextField();
    campoTextoAlbum.setBounds(62, 120, 231, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoAlbum);
    campoTextoAlbum.setColumns(10);

    /*Boton Modificar*/
    botonModificar = new JButton("Modify");
    botonModificar.setBounds(62, 151, 89, 23);
    botonModificar.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(botonModificar);

    /*Boton Eliminar*/
    botonEliminar = new JButton("Delete");
    botonEliminar.setBounds(161, 151, 89, 23);
    botonEliminar.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(botonEliminar);

    /*Etiqueta Canciones*/
    etiquetaCanciones = new JLabel("Tracks:");
    etiquetaCanciones.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaCanciones.setBounds(10, 206, 76, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaCanciones);

    /*Lista de Canciones*/
    scrollListadoCanciones=new JScrollPane();
    listaCanciones = new JList();
    modeloLista=new DefaultListModel();
    scrollListadoCanciones.setBounds(10, 226, 210, 163);
    getContentPane().add(scrollListadoCanciones);
    scrollListadoCanciones.setViewportView(listaCanciones);

    /*Boton Eliminar II*/
    botonEliminar2 = new JButton("Delete");
    botonEliminar2.setBounds(226, 366, 101, 23);
    getContentPane().add(botonEliminar2);

    /*Boton Añadir*/
    botonAdd = new JButton("Add");
    botonAdd.setBounds(226, 332, 101, 23);
    botonAdd.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(botonAdd);

    /*Combo Artista*/
    elegirArtista = new JComboBox();
    modeloCombo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    miGenerador=new Generador();
    elegirArtista.addActionListener(this);
    elegirArtista.setBounds(66, 10, 227, 20);
    getContentPane().add(elegirArtista);
    miGenerador.llenarComboArtistas(modeloCombo, elegirArtista);


    /*Combo Albumes*/
    elegirAlbum = new JComboBox();
    elegirAlbum.setBounds(66, 35, 227, 20);
    elegirAlbum.addActionListener(this);
    getContentPane().add(elegirAlbum);  
}

public void setCoordinador(Coordinador miCoordinador){
    this.miCoordinador=miCoordinador;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) {
    if(evento.getSource()==elegirArtista){
        if(elegirArtista.getSelectedIndex()>0){
            miGenerador.llenarComboAlbumes(modeloCombo, elegirAlbum, elegirArtista);
            campoTextoArtista.setText((String)elegirArtista.getSelectedItem());

        }
    }

    if(evento.getSource()==elegirAlbum){
        campoTextoAlbum.setText((String)elegirAlbum.getSelectedItem());
    }

    if(elegirAlbum.getSelectedIndex()>=0){
        AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
        AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();

        albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
        miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones(albumVO, modeloLista, listaCanciones, albumDAO);
    }

    if(evento.getSource()==botonModificar){
        try{
            AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
            AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();

            String nuevoNombreAlbum=campoTextoAlbum.getText();
            albumVO.setNombreAlbum(elegirAlbum.getSelectedItem().toString());
            albumDAO.modificarAlbum(albumVO, nuevoNombreAlbum);

        }catch(Exception excepcion){
            excepcion.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if(evento.getSource()==botonEliminar){
        int respuesta=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar el Album?","Confirmación",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if(respuesta==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();
            AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
            ArtistaDAO artistaDAO=new ArtistaDAO();
            ArtistaVO artistaVO=new ArtistaVO();

            artistaVO.setArtistName(campoTextoArtista.getText());
            albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
            albumDAO.eliminarAlbum(artistaDAO, artistaVO, albumDAO, albumVO);
        }
    }

    if(evento.getSource()==botonAdd){
        VistaCancionesAdd ventanaCancionesAdd=new VistaCancionesAdd();
        AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
        AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();

        albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
        ventanaCancionesAdd.abrirVentanaCanciones(campoTextoArtista, campoTextoAlbum, albumDAO, albumVO, modeloLista, listaCanciones);
        ventanaCancionesAdd.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public void abrirVentana(JTextField campoTextoArtista2, DefaultListModel modeloLista, JList listadoAlbumes){

    miGenerador.llenarComboArtistas(modeloCombo, elegirArtista);
    miGenerador.llenarComboAlbumes(modeloCombo, elegirAlbum, elegirArtista);
    elegirArtista.setSelectedItem(campoTextoArtista2.getText());
    elegirAlbum.setSelectedItem(listadoAlbumes.getSelectedValue());
}

}
```

Y es así: 
[image: VistaAlbumesBuscar]

Y esta es la otra:

`VistaCancionesAdd`

```
public class VistaCancionesAdd extends JFrame{

private Coordinador miCoordinador;
private JTextField campoTextoArtistaCancion, campoTextoAlbumCancion, campoTextoCancion;
private JLabel etiquetaArtista, etiquetaAlbum, etiquetaCanciones, etiquetaCancion;
private JSeparator separador, separador2;
private JList listaCanciones;
private DefaultListModel modeloLista;
private JScrollPane scrollListadoCanciones;
private JButton botonAdd, botonAdd2;
private Generador miGenerador;

/**
 * Iniciar la Ventana
 */
public VistaCancionesAdd() {
    iniciarVentana();
}

/**
 * Contenido de la ventana
 */
private void iniciarVentana() {

    /*Propiedades del Frame*/
    setTitle("Canciones: A\u00F1adir");
    setBounds(100, 100, 354, 374);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    /*Etiqueta Artista*/
    etiquetaArtista = new JLabel("Artista:");
    etiquetaArtista.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaArtista.setBounds(10, 11, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaArtista);

    /*Campo Texto Artista (No editable)*/
    campoTextoArtistaCancion = new JTextField();
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setBounds(66, 10, 251, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoArtistaCancion);
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setEditable(false);
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setColumns(10);

    /*Etiqueta Album*/
    etiquetaAlbum = new JLabel("Album:");
    etiquetaAlbum.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaAlbum.setBounds(10, 43, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaAlbum);

    /*Campo texto Album (No editable)*/
    campoTextoAlbumCancion = new JTextField();
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setBounds(66, 41, 251, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoAlbumCancion);
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setEditable(false);
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setColumns(10);

    /*Separador 1*/
    separador = new JSeparator();
    separador.setBounds(0, 70, 338, 2);
    getContentPane().add(separador);

    /*Etiqueta Canciones*/
    etiquetaCanciones = new JLabel("Canciones:");
    etiquetaCanciones.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaCanciones.setBounds(10, 83, 74, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaCanciones);

    /*Listado Canciones*/
    scrollListadoCanciones=new JScrollPane();
    listaCanciones = new JList();
    modeloLista=new DefaultListModel();
    scrollListadoCanciones.setBounds(10, 103, 216, 138);
    getContentPane().add(scrollListadoCanciones);
    scrollListadoCanciones.setViewportView(listaCanciones);

    /*Boton Añadir*/
    botonAdd = new JButton("Modificar");
    botonAdd.setBounds(239, 218, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(botonAdd);

    /*Separador 2*/
    separador2 = new JSeparator();
    separador2.setBounds(0, 262, 338, 2);
    getContentPane().add(separador2);

    /*Etiqueta Cancion*/
    etiquetaCancion = new JLabel("Canci\u00F3n:");
    etiquetaCancion.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    etiquetaCancion.setBounds(10, 293, 62, 14);
    getContentPane().add(etiquetaCancion);

    /*Campo Texto Cancion*/
    campoTextoCancion = new JTextField();
    campoTextoCancion.setBounds(82, 292, 144, 20);
    getContentPane().add(campoTextoCancion);
    campoTextoCancion.setColumns(10);

    /*Boton Añadir 2*/
    botonAdd2 = new JButton("A\u00F1adir");
    botonAdd2.setBounds(239, 291, 89, 23);
    getContentPane().add(botonAdd2);
}
public void setCoordinador(Coordinador miCoordinador){
    this.miCoordinador=miCoordinador;
}

public void abrirVentanaCanciones(JTextField campoTextoArtista, JTextField campoTextoAlbum, AlbumDAO albumDAO, AlbumVO albumVO, DefaultListModel modeloLista, JList listaCanciones){
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setText(campoTextoArtista.getText());
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setText(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
    miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones2(albumVO, modeloLista, listaCanciones, albumDAO);
}
}
```

Y es así:

[image: VistaCancionesAdd]

Pues a partir de `vistaAlbumesBuscar` intento abrir `VistaCancionesAdd` para ello utilizo este método que esta dentro de `VistaCancionesAdd`

```
 public void abrirVentanaCanciones(JTextField campoTextoArtista, JTextField campoTextoAlbum, AlbumDAO albumDAO, AlbumVO albumVO, DefaultListModel modeloLista, JList listaCanciones){
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setText(campoTextoArtista.getText());
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setText(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
    miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones(albumVO, modeloLista, listaCanciones, albumDAO);
   }
```

Y lo llamo así desde `VistaAlbumesBuscar`:

```
 if(evento.getSource()==botonAdd){
        VistaCancionesAdd ventanaCancionesAdd=new VistaCancionesAdd();
        AlbumVO albumVO=new AlbumVO();
        AlbumDAO albumDAO=new AlbumDAO();

        albumVO.setNombreAlbum(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
        ventanaCancionesAdd.abrirVentanaCanciones(campoTextoArtista, campoTextoAlbum, albumDAO, albumVO, modeloLista, listaCanciones);
        ventanaCancionesAdd.setVisible(true);
      }
```

Este es el método `llenarListaCanciones()`

```
 public void llenarListaCanciones(AlbumVO albumVO, DefaultListModel modeloLista,JList listaCanciones, AlbumDAO albumDAO){

    Conexion conexion=new Conexion();
    //modeloLista.removeAllElements();
    try{
        String consultaSql="select name from track where albumid=?";
        PreparedStatement sqlNombreCancion=conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(consultaSql);
        sqlNombreCancion.setInt(1, albumDAO.getIdAlbum(albumVO));
        ResultSet resultado=sqlNombreCancion.executeQuery();
        while(resultado.next()){
            modeloLista.addElement(resultado.getString("name"));
            listaCanciones.setModel(modeloLista);
        }
        sqlNombreCancion.close();
        conexion.cerrarConexion();
    }catch(SQLException excepcion){
        excepcion.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

Pues en `VistaAlbumesBuscar` cuando doy al boton Add (tal y como está en la imagen) me salta esta excepción:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at vista.VistaCancionesAdd.abrirVentanaCanciones(VistaCancionesAdd.java:119)
at vista.VistaAlbumesBuscar.actionPerformed(VistaAlbumesBuscar.java:215)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

No hace falta que nadie me explique lo que es la excepción `NullPointerException` ya que significa que arroja un valor null(no quiero ofender a nadie con esto, pero ya me paso que me respondieron lo que significaba y eso no solucionó mi problema), si no que se que el problema está en `llenarListaCanciones()` pero no logro identificar que parte, por eso pido ayuda.

Muchas gracias.

**#ACTUALIZACION 1**

Esta es la línea 119:

`miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones2(albumVO, modeloLista, listaCanciones, albumDAO);`

Comment: Exactamente que hay en esta linea `VistaCancionesAdd.java:119` la 119

Comment: @NeoChiri, como comentario, lo más sencillo y eficaz es realizar un debug y así vas revisando el contenido de las variables, te puedo asegurar que de esta forma detectarías un problema con rapidez.

Comment: @RosendoRopher me parece que esa linea de código  esta dentro del método abrirVentanaCanciones()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo te aconsejo ver bien la traza del error e intentar ubicar lo que puede estar fallando.

Según la traza el error se lanza aquí : `vista.VistaCancionesAdd.abrirVentanaCanciones(VistaCancionesAdd.java:119)` entonces ubica en tu clase `VistaCancionesAdd` la linea 119 y fíjate cual es el objeto que estas intentando acceder y/o modificar. Porque lo que está pasando es eso, estás intentando modificar o acceder a algo, que en ese momento no ha sido inicializado, instanciado, etc.

No puedo saberlo porque simplemente no veo los números de línea del código y tampoco has colocado los imports (para copiar tus clases con la cantidad de lineas exactas como para evaluar la traza), pero analizándolo un poco. Tienes el método `abrirVentanaCanciones` que según la traza es desde donde se origina el problema.

Tu método luce así

```
public void abrirVentanaCanciones(JTextField campoTextoArtista, JTextField    campoTextoAlbum, AlbumDAO albumDAO, AlbumVO albumVO, DefaultListModel modeloLista, JList listaCanciones){
    campoTextoArtistaCancion.setText(campoTextoArtista.getText());
    campoTextoAlbumCancion.setText(campoTextoAlbum.getText());
    miGenerador.llenarListaCanciones(albumVO, modeloLista, listaCanciones, albumDAO);
}
```

Antes de hacer cualquier cosa en este método, verifica que todo es distinto de `null` por decir algo

```
if(AlbumDAO != null && modeloLista != null && listaCanciones != null) {
    //logica actual
}
```

De esa manera evitas este tipo de inconvenientes.

Favor suministra el código de la línea indicada para ampliar la respuesta, en base a ello.

Comment: Ya he añadido la línea 119, lo siento, no me di cuenta de ese detalle.

Comment: @NeoChiri de igual manera, realiza lo que te recomiendo o como dice un comentario, verifica que `miGenerador` está inicializado para ese momento y también los demás atributos que pasas como argumentos a ese metodo `llenarListaCanciones`

Comment: Efectivamente `miGenerador` no estaba iniciado en `VistaCancionesAdd`, no se como no me di cuenta; ahora me ha surgido otro problema, que al abrir `VistaCancionesAdd` si me rellena los `JTextField` superiores pero no la lista de Canciones.